# Read files from unix server with ItemReaders in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm new to spring batch and I'm using below code to read files from unix server in spring batch application.

```
public class test2
 {
    static String user = "myusername";
    static String host = "user@remotehost";
    static String password = "mypasswd";
    static String port = 22;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, JSchException
    {
        JSch jsch=new JSch();
        Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
        session.setPassword(password);
        Properties config = new Properties ();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        Channel channel=session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        ChannelSftp channelsftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
        channelSftp.cd("unix directory");
        List<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list = channelSftp.ls("*"+fileName+"*");
        // Processing the files here
    }
 }
```

Is there any other way to read files from unix using any item readers. Please suggest

Thanks in Advance